# Using JavaMail from a webapp in GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, jakarta-mail, glassfish-3

I have set up a JavaMail session in a backing bean for my JSF application, and it turns out to be fairly easy to send e-mail.  However depending on network conditions, it can take a fair amount of time.  The **Transport.send()** method will block the calling thread until the e-mail is sent or the protocol fails somehow.

My question is:  Is this okay to do in a JSF backing bean, considering the possibility of many users accessing the server at the same time?

I can create an application-scoped worker thread that would work off of a BlockingQueue to handle all the e-mail in background.   Is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's better to move anything that uses the network (and thus may be delayed unpredictably) into a separate thread.

Comment: that's what I needed to know.  The examples on the web don't mention this aspect so I was left to wonder if the GlassFish architecture provided for its ServeLets (in my case JSF 2 Facelets) being blocked in this way.

Answer (score 2):

A posibility is to have an ejb producing jms-messages, an mdb that consumes the messages asyncronously and invokes the Transport.send()

look at this example: http://faeddalberto.blogspot.com/2011/03/sending-email-with-ejb-3-mdb-message.html